# Get first word of match of last line

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I want to parse through a log file formatted like this:

```
INFO: Successfully received REQUEST_ID: 1111 from 164.12.1.11
INFO: Successfully received REQUEST_ID: 2222 from 164.12.2.22
ERROR: Some error
INFO: Successfully received REQUEST_ID: 3333 from 164.12.3.33
INFO: Successfully received REQUEST_ID: 4444 from 164.12.4.44
WARNING: Some warning
INFO: Some other info
```

I want a script that outputs 4444. So extract the next word after ^.*REQUEST_ID: from the last line that contains the pattern ^.*REQUEST_ID.

What I have so far:

```
ID=$(sed -n -e 's/^.*REQUEST_ID: //p' $logfile | tail -n 1)
```

For lines match the pattern matches for, it deletes all the text matching the match thus leaving only the text after the match and prints it. Then I tail it to get the last line. How to do make it so it only prints the first word?

And is there a more efficient way of doing this then having it piped to tail?

Answer (score 4):

With awk:

```
awk '
     $4 ~ /REQUEST_ID:/{val=$5}
     END {print val}
    ' file.csv
```

`$4 ~ /REQUEST_ID:/` : Match lines in which Field # 4 match `REQUEST_ID:`.

`{val=$5}` : Store the value of field 5 in the variable val.

`END {print val}` : On closing the file, print the last value stored.

I have used a regex match to allow for some variance on the string, and yet get a match. A more lenient match will be (a match at any place of the line):

```
awk ' /REQUEST_ID/ {val=$5}
     END {print val}
    ' file.csv
```

If you value (or need) more speed than robustness, then use (Quoting needed):

```
awk '
     $4 == "REQUEST_ID:" {val=$5}
     END {print val}
    ' file.csv
```

Comment: Re `REQUEST_ID:` - Being a literal, you can use `$4 == "REQUEST_ID:"` - a literal search is typically faster than a regex search.  (+1)

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -nE 's/.* REQUEST_ID: ([0-9]+) .*/\1/p' | tail -n 1
```

Output:

```
4444
```

---

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po 'REQUEST_ID: \K[0-9]+' file | tail -n 1
```

Output:

```
4444
```

---

`-P`: Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.

`-o`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

`\K`: Drop everything before that point from the internal record.

Comment: even a tail is fast, try to avoid piping when possible (especialy with sed)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/^.*REQUEST_ID: \([0-9]\{1,\}\) .*/ {s//\1/;h;}
    $!d
    x' ${logfile}
```

- posix version
- print an empty line if no occurence, the next word (assuming it's a number here)

**Principe:**

- if line contain *REQUEST_ID*

  - extract the *next* number
  - put it in hold buffer
- if not the end, delete the current content (and cycle to next line)
- load holding buffer (and print the line ending the cycle)

Comment: Nice idea with hold buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the number and replace with that value:

```
sed -e 's/^.*REQUEST_ID: \([0-9]*\).*$/\1/g' $logfile
```

Comment: This has several issues. *1:* OP wants *only* the last matched value. *2:* It will print *all* non-matching lines, because by default that is what `sed` does - it needs option `-n` and command `p`, somehow . *3:* It doesn't need the `g`, as there is only 1 field to match. *4:* it will match everything to the end of the line if the first character of the *expected* numeric string is non-numeric - it needs `\+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Print field where line and column meet.

```
awk 'FNR == 5 {print $5}' file 
4444
```

Comment: OK for this sample but OP is a bit more generic and last reference is certainly often not on the 5th line

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` alternative if you don't know the position of the search word.

```
tac file | awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i=="REQUEST_ID:") {print $(i+1);exit}}'
```

yet, another one without looping

```
tac file | awk -vRS=" " 'n{print;exit} /REQUEST_ID:/{n=1}'
```